# Partial select of left joined table with doctrine query builder

Tags: doctrine

When querying one table using the doctrine query builder a partial select can be written like this:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('person');
$queryBuilder->addSelect('partial person.{id, name}');
```

How can one write a partial select be written for a left joined table? I tried something like this, but can't figure out the correct syntax:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('person');
$queryBuilder->join('person.address');
$queryBuilder->addSelect('partial person.{id, name} person.address.city'); // ???
```

My goal would be to select only parts of the `Person` and the `Address` object when executing the query to be more memory efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off for your join operation. You have to give an alias when using [`join`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods). From there, you can just use the same syntax to query your partial `Address` object:

```php
// In a method of PersonRepository
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('person')
    ->select(['partial person.{id, name}', 'partial address.{id, city}'])
    ->join('person.address', 'address');
```

Notice that I added `id` to the fields retrieved for `Address`. If you don't, Doctrine will give you the following error:

> **Error:** The partial field selection of class `Path\To\Entity\Address` must contain the identifier

---

As a side note, you said you wanted to write this select for a left joined table. If you want to perform a `LEFT JOIN`, you need to use `leftJoin` instead of `join` (the signature of both methods is the same).

Comment: Hi, how can i change field name: partial person.{id, name} -> to partial person.{id, name as custome_name} ?
``as`` dosnt worcking